# Pyspark - How do I convert date/timestamp of format like /Date(1593786688000+0200)/ in pyspark?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I've a dataframe with CreateDate column with this format:

```
CreateDate
/Date(1593786688000+0200)/
/Date(1446032157000+0100)/
/Date(1533904635000+0200)/
/Date(1447839805000+0100)/
/Date(1589451249000+0200)/
```

and I want to convert that format to date/timestamp, so the excepted output will be:

```
CreateDate
2020-07-03 14:31:28 +02:00
2015-10-28 11:35:57 +01:00
2018-08-10 12:37:15 +02:00
2015-11-18 09:43:25 +01:00
2020-05-14 10:14:09 +02:00
```

I have this query in SQL that gives the desired output and that can help to develop:

```
cast(convert(VARCHAR(30), DATEADD(Second, convert(BIGINT, left(replace(replace(CreateDate, '/date(', ''), ')/', ''), 13)) / 1000, '1970-01-01 00:00:00'), 20) + ' ' + '+' + left(right(replace(replace(CreateDate, '/date(', ''), ')/', ''), 4), 2) + ':' + right(replace(replace(CreateDate, '/date(', ''), ')/', ''), 2) AS DATETIMEOFFSET(0)) AS CreateDate
```

Can anyone please help me in achieving this?

Thank you!

Comment: `sparkDF.withColumn("CreateDate_new", date_format("CreateDate", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")` Does this work? You can import date_format.  `from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format`

Comment: Nop :\ I'm getting null values. I tried to_date too, but unfortunately is returning null too. Thanks a lot for you help and comment !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`regexp_extract`](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/regexp_extract.html) to pull timestamp and time offset.

Then [`from_unixtime`](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/from_unixtime.html) to convert seconds to timestamp. Note that `from_unixtime` expects seconds, while you timestamp is in milliseconds, that's why we leave out `000` (naively assuming that in your data this is indeed zeros in all of the records, otherwise you'll need to adjust this a bit).

```scala
val re = """/Date\((\d+)000(\+\d+)"""

df.withColumn("ts", from_unixtime(regexp_extract($"CreateDate", re, 1)))
  .withColumn("tz_offset", regexp_extract($"CreateDate", re, 2))
  .show(false)
+--------------------------+-------------------+---------+
|CreateDate                |ts                 |tz_offset|
+--------------------------+-------------------+---------+
|/Date(1593786688000+0200)/|2020-07-03 16:31:28|+0200    |
+--------------------------+-------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kombajn. I picked up part of your code and I created this:

.withColumn('CreateDateNew', concat(expr("dateadd(second, cast(left(replace(replace(CreateDate, '/Date(', ''),')/', ''), 13) as bigint)/1000, '1970-01-01 00:00:00')"), lit(" "), regexp_replace(regexp_extract("CreateDate", re, 2), "(\\d{2})(\\d{2})" , "$1:$2" )))

 and I got the desire output too